# How replace word tables chr(13)?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-table

I am working on copy and past the word tables to excel. but there are a lot of 'enter' key in word tables. could I know how to replace the the enter key in whole word tables.
I am encountering issue" wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment"

Comment: Try replace `With Selection.Find` with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Find`, there's no need to select range 99% of the time (so you can probably delete `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Select` too).

Comment: What are you trying to replace carriage return ("enter" key) with?  `.Text = ">P"` should be  `.Text = "^p"` and `^p` in `.Replacement.Text = "^p"` should be replaced with your replacement character.

Comment: Please also read on [how to avoid using Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1), you do not need to activate/select your worksheet/cell 99% of the time (In fact, it's bad practice)

Comment: See, for example: https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?8900-Help-with-VBA-to-extract-data-from-Word-to-Excel&p=36586&viewfull=1#post36586

Comment: You likely also need to eliminate the end-of-cell marks, not just paragraph marks.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Bro, how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember. But I do know it is a separate character. You should be able to find it with an Internet search.

Comment: You really should read code in the link I posted...

Comment: @macropod bro, I read it, but the Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll is not working

Comment: The code *as posted* in the link works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one problem with this code.

The first is that you are not setting `oLookWordDoc` to point to a document, so none of the Word code will work.

Second, you have two variables pointing to the same table, `oLookwordTbl` and `r`. You only need one of these.

Third, you are selecting the table to run `Find` instead of simply using the `Find` method of `Table.Range`.

Fourth, your find and replacement texts are incorrect.

The tidied code below will replace the paragraph marks in the table with a space.

```
Dim oLookWordDoc As Word.document
Dim oLookwordTbl As Word.Table
Dim iRow As Long 'row index

'you need to set oLookWordDoc to point to a document here

'Grab the word table
Set oLookwordTbl = oLookWordDoc.Tables(1)
With oLookwordTbl.Range.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
'rows 2 - end
For iRow = 2 To oLookwordTbl.Rows.Count
    oLookwordTbl.Rows(iRow).Range.Copy
    'Paste
    xWs.Paste
    xWs.Cells(xWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Offset(1).Select
Next
```

Comment: Hi Timothy,
Thanks for your time to reply this.
However, coding having issue "this command is not available" while running {.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll}  system show: wdReplaceAll=2 ( helight yellow color )

Comment: @ZhaoYang - Sounds as though you don’t have a reference to the Word library.

Comment: Hi Timothy, 
I verified the 'Microsoft word 16.0 object library' was enabled.

Comment: I paste full code with your advise. the .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll is not working.

Comment: @ZhaoYang - the code is correct so if it isn’t working there is something else wrong. You need to edit your question, or post a new one, and show the full code you are using.

Comment: cool! I will raise new questions

Answer (score 0):

`With Selection.find` references the Excel selection object. But you want to work with the Word selection object.

Do you have a variable for the word application, e.g. appWord?
Use this: `With appWord.Selection.find`

If not `With oLookWordDoc.parent.selection.find` should work